# how can i remove all commas at the end of the string?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to remove all the commas that are in last of every string i tried s.rstrip it work only for the last comma

`l = [['kjkng,rkggg,,,,,,,,,,', 'aaaa, , ', 'sssssss, , , '],['rjfjrejn lelkkd ,,,,,'], ['fffff , , ,'],[], .....]]`

i want result as

`l = [['kjkng,rkggg', 'aaaa', 'sssssss'],['rjfjrejn lelkkd'],['fffff'],[], .....]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this because you have a nested list:

```
>>> [[b.rstrip(', ') for b in a] for a in l]

[['kjkng,rkggg', 'aaaa', 'sssssss'], ['rjfjrejn lelkkd'], ['fffff']]
```

Comment: the inner brackets are redundant

Comment: OP want this : `[['kjkng,rkggg', 'aaaa', 'sssssss'],['rjfjrejn lelkkd'],['fffff'],[], .....]]`

Comment: @XxJames07- your code is wrong

Comment: what code are you talking about? I was just warning you about the redundant brackets

Comment: @XxJames07-, I run this code from second part of your answer : `final = [x.rstrip(", ") for x in lst for lst in l]`  and get this error : `not defined lst`

Comment: sorry I just switched the order of the for loops in the list comprehension.Now i've fixed it

Answer (score 2):

let's look around the cases:

1. List of strings

in this case the simplest solution is to do a `list comprehension` and use the `str.rstrip(", ")` to remove commas and spaces at the end of the string.

```
l = [x.rstrip(", ") for x in l]
```

2. Nested List of strings

in this case, illustrated as an example, you can do in a `recursive` way and a `linear` way

- recursive

do a function wich takes a `list` and returns another `list` like in the code:

```
def remcommas(lst:list):
    final = []
    for x in lst:
        if x.isinstance(x,list):
            x = remcommas(x)
        final.append(x)
    return final
```

this works if your list is nested but it's not the optimal solution.

- linear

this will still use `str.rstrip()` and work with list of list but it has a constrain:

- this will work on lists with a structure like what you have (`list[list[str]]`)

But it's probably the best for now that i can think of, uses `list comprehension`:

```
final = [x.rstrip(", ") for lst in l for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = []
for elist in l:
   ires = []
   for elm in elist:
       ires.append(elm.replace(',','')
   res.append(ires)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do it.

```
text = [['kjkng,rkggg,,,,,,', 'aaaa, , , ,', 'sssssss , , , , ,'], 
['rjfjrejn lelkkd,,,,,,,'], ['fffff, , , , ,']]

text = [[new_value.rstrip(' , ') for new_value in j] for j in text]

print(text
```

[['kjkng,rkggg', 'aaaa', 'sssssss'], ['rjfjrejn lelkkd'], ['fffff']]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

l = [['kjkng,rkggg,,,,,,,,,,', 'aaaa, , ', 'sssssss, , , '],['rjfjrejn lelkkd ,,,,,'], ['fffff , , ,'],[]]

regex = re.compile(r"[, ]*$", re.IGNORECASE)
res = []
for arr in l:
    res.append([])
    for s in arr:
        res[-1].append(regex.sub('',s))
```

Comment: Its a good habit if you explain code for the sake of other readers coming to this post